# Firefox: Can't select text value of input field nested in "a" tag

Tags: html, firefox

I have an input field nested in "a" tag. The bellow markup can be tested at: http://codepen.io/anon/full/mtFIs. It works as expected (input field text is selectable) in Chrome, but it doesn't in Firefox 20.0. Any ideas how to make the text selectable?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <a href="#">
    <input title="test" value="select me" type="text">
  </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically what you are trying is wrong but if you STILL want, you can use `onclick` event with `window.location` or `window.open` with or without `_blank`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8yEJj/)

```
<span onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank')">
    <input title="test" value="select me" type="text" />
</span>
```

Answer (score 5):

`<a>` elements **may not** contain `<input>` elements in HTML.

Write [valid](http://validator.w3.org/) HTML instead.